# Fourier transform of $\lvert x^2-1\rvert $

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

One of the exercises of my assignment was to determine the Fourier transform of function 
$$f(x)=\lvert x^2-1\rvert$$
The domain wasn't specified. First I was puzzled since $f$ isn't a $L^1$ function. 
If I were to calculate 
$$\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_\mathbb{R} \lvert x^2-1\rvert e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\,dx$$ I would calculate it separately on $\langle-\infty, -1], \langle-1,1\rangle$ and $[1, +\infty \rangle$ but in case of real domain, it doesn't converge (first and third integral).

In case of complex domain, separate parts converge depending on the imaginary part of $\xi$, but not at the same time so the whole integral diverges.

Am I missing something here? I would have said at first that the Fourier transform of this function isn't defined, but why would it be an exercise then...

Comment: Does your course include distributions? If not, you'll have to ask your teacher what is meant with this exercise...

Comment: It does include distributions, but I don't see how does it change things.

Comment: Well, since $f$ is not an $L^1$ function, the Fourier transform isn't defined by the usual integral. Instead, $\mathcal{F}(f)$ is going to be a distribution.

Comment: I think I realize now. I have to think of $f$ as a distribution so the Fourier transform is defined as \begin{align*}  \langle \mathcal{F}(f), \phi\rangle=\langle \overset{\sim}{f}, \mathcal{F}(\phi) \rangle  \end{align*} and calculate integral $\int_{R} f(-\xi) \mathcal{F}(\phi)(\xi)d\xi$, where $\overset{\sim}{f(x)}=f(-x)$. But doesn't the problem with the convergence of integrals stay?

Comment: If $\widetilde{f}$ is a distribution which doesn't come from a locally integrable function, then the action $\langle \widetilde{f},\cdot \rangle$ is not given by an integral. (Think of the Dirac delta, for example.)

Comment: In that case how is it defined? Seems like my notes don't cover this. When we talked about functions as distributions, they were always locally integrable so it was okay.

Comment: I was talking about distributions which don't come from functions **at all**. (Think of the **Dirac delta**, for example.)

Comment: I understood your comment, but I don't know how should expression $\langle \overset{\sim}{f}, \cdot\rangle $ be defined if not as an integral, for $f(x)=|x^2-1|$. I know Dirac delta isn't a regular distribution, but other than that I don't know any or how would they be defined.

Comment: It's hard to say how you are meant to solve this exercise without knowing what other examples you have come across. Maybe split into cases to get rid of the absolute values, and get one part that you can do by integration and another part where you can use known facts such as the Fourier transform of $1$ and what happens on the transform side when you multiply by $x$...? I think the best person to ask about this would be your teacher.

Comment: I will try. Thank you for your effort nevertheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fourier transform of a distribution is defined as
$$(\mathcal F[f], \phi) = (f, \mathcal F[\phi]).$$
That is, the action of $\mathcal F[f]$ on $\phi$ is given by the rhs of this identity, where we know that $\mathcal F[\phi]$ is well-defined and is again a valid test function.

We can find the transforms of $1$ and of $x^2$ by finding the transform of $\delta^{(n)}$ and also can find the transform of $|x^2 - 1| - (x^2 - 1)$ directly to get
$$(|x^2 - 1|, e^{-2 \pi i \xi x}) =
-\frac {\delta''(\xi)} {4 \pi^2} - \delta(\xi) +
 \frac {\sin 2 \pi \xi - 2 \pi \xi \cos 2 \pi \xi} {\pi^3 \xi^3}.$$